# How do I access localhost:8080 running on Ubuntu from Windows running in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I have the IP address for Ubuntu machine, and I want to access the application running on localhost in Ubuntu from my virtual Windows box. Is there a way to do it? Typing the [inet address]:8080 doesn't work.

Answer (score 35):

Windows has its "own" `localhost`, so you have to "help" it find Ubuntu's one.

In your virtual machine, go to this ip `http://10.0.2.2/` and it should work. You can edit windows host file to make `localhost` point to that ip so you don't have to remember it.

In: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Add:

```
10.0.2.2 localhost
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

You could set the virtual machine to use a bridged connection. That way the virtual machine will get its own IP-address, and you should be able to connect to the host machine.

1. Right click on the Virtual Machine (while it is not running)
2. Choose '**Settings**'
3. Choose '**Network**'
4. Under the '**Adapter 1**' tab, set '**Attached to**' to '**Bridged Adapter**'.

Comment: This worked like a charm !

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure the web server process is running. Type `localhost:8080` in a browser window on your Ubuntu machine. If you get the page you were expecting proceed to next step, otherwise start the webserver process and retry.

Second, make sure that both machines are on the same sub-network. i.e. something like `192.168.x.y/255.255.255.0` and `192.168.x.z/255.255.25.0` If not, make necessary adjustments and proceed to next step.

Third, check if a firewall is running on your ubuntu server. If so, check if the desired port is open (`8080` in your case). If you do not want to open the port to public access you can configure a rule to accept only traffic from the local sub-net.

Edit: Step 0. Make the settings suggested in the answer by @Eeroz

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu you have to first disable your firewall.

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Now find your ipv4 address from system settings-> Network and click on arrow of connected wifi to get more information about it.There you will find ipv4 address of your pc. Then you can use localhost of your pc as

> http://ipv4:portno/yourpagename

Do not forget to enable firewall after completing your work.Use-

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you have determined that it is your firewall, I would advise adding this rule instead of disabling your firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

When you are finished you should run:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

find the numbers in brackets. Say it's `[ 1]` and `[ 3]`:

```
sudo ufw delete 1 3
```

Then, if you are on virtual box you will navigate to `http://10.0.2.2:8080` if you have your network set as `NAT`. You can do this for any port and it will work the same.

Even though this is some extra work, you should never disable your firewall even on a secure network.